# How to pass custom class name on react and use scss?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass

I am trying to create a react component that has the class name as props being passed,

I have managed sending the props part successfully, however when I try to set the scss for the updated class name, I could not find a way to fix that, all of your input is appreciated.

### Code of the component

Code of injecting the custom style class
[image: Code of the Variation]
Styles of the Variation
[image: Styles of the Variation]

### Output

Output of the Variation Class
[image: Output of the Variation Class]

Output of the Stylesheet
[image: Output of the Stylesheet]

not sure what I am missing to connect all of them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `&.secondary` to indicate it's an additional class and not a nested element?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Phil, your SCSS should be using `&.secondary` as the selector.

As for the difference in your scss class IDs and them not matching when you pass `${variant}` to the className, your issue is that you are passing a raw string as the variant to the `className` and are using CSS modules for your SCSS (this is what handles namespacing them/adding the unique characters). To fix this, you need to use the imported style rather than a raw string for the `className`.

The way I usually address this is with an `enum` as the prop for different variants, or if there are only two a `boolean`, and then apply the imported style accordingly. A quick example of this, using your code would be:

```
const SectionTitle: FC<SectionTitleProps> = ({ title, isSecondary = false }) => (
  <h3
    className={`${styles.SectionTitle}${isSecondary ? styles.secondary : ''}`}
    ...
  >
    ...
  </h3>
);
```

I also find the `classnames` library helpful for this. It allows you to achieve the above with something I find a bit more readable, such as:

```
<h3
  className={classNames(styles.SectionTitle, { [styles.secondary]: isSecondary } )}
  ...
>
  ...
</h3>
```

**EDIT:** Also including an example using `classnames` with an `enum` for different variants:

```
enum TitleVarient {
  Default,
  Secondary,
  Accent,
}

const SectionTitle: FC<SectionTitleProps> = ({
  title, 
  variant = TitleVarient.Default,
}) => (
  <h3
    className={classNames(styles.SectionTitle, {
      [styles.secondary]: variant === TitleVarient.Secondary,
      [styles.accent]: variant === TitleVarient.Accent,
    })}
    ...
  >
    ...
  </h3>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,

I think what I am aiming to do is to send different options ( e.g secondary, accent, ... ).
So I was hoping there would be a way to do that from the function side, and yes I totally agree I missed the &.secondary there on my screenshot, however it's there now. do you think that ```classnames``` library would help?

Comment: The important part is including the imported CSS module class ID rather than a string. You could achieve this with multiple conditional strings similar to `${isSecondary ? styles.secondary : ''}` but I find using something like the `classnames` library helpful. I've added an edit with an example for this using an `enum` to handle more than 2 variants.